# addClass that changes bg-image but without a flicker on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, preload

I'm running a function on every keyboard keyup to monitor a text field.

Depending on the input, I am using jquery to `.removeClass("classwithBGImage").addClass("classwithnewBGimage")`

This is working nicely, expect on the first load there is a flicker in the background image.

I have tried preloading the images with Javascript and CSS, even tried using a sprite - but there is always a flicker on the first load when `.removeClass("classwithBGImage").addClass("classwithnewBGimage")` is triggered.

Update:
Seems to be a documented chrome bug:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=102706

As witnessed in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QpvUQ/2/

Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: You might do a "dip to black" effect if nothing else works. This would reduce any jarring effect a sudden flicker might cause. But this would depend on why you are changing the image. If you're trying to make a pseudo animation, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the background-image to a `div` positioned absolutely and `left:-99999px`.

```
#preload{
   background-image : url(large-image.png);
   position:absolute;
   left:-99999px;
}
```

Later, use it for the actual div

```
.classwithnewBGimage{
  background-image : url(large-image.png);
}
```

This is one of the hacks that I am aware of for pre-loading images so that they don't take time when you actually use them.

---

Also, `.removeClass()` without arguments does nothing. To avoid flickers use smooth transitioning.

```
.stylesWithoutImage{
 ///
}

.classwithnewBGimage{
//img
}
```

Comment: Normally, I would say this would work, but I already tried preloading the images with javascript, as well as like you mentioned with CSS, and I even tried using a sprite. There's always a flicker on the first load when I trigger the class change with the text input entry.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. The solution purposed by Robin should work. Could you please create a working example in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I've edited the original question with a jsfiddle that duplicates my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Move.js](http://visionmedia.github.com/move.js/) you can Animate CSS Changes.

```
move('.box')
  .set('background-image', 'url(img)')
  .end();
```

PS : Not tried but it say's you can animate CSS with it.

Answer (score 0):

I did an implementation with only CSS to do the same than your jsfiddle.

*How it works?*

```
.class {
  background: url(...);
}

.class:hover {
  background: url(...);
}
```

I left the JS code if you need to do it with Javascript, but with only CSS should be enought.

http://jsfiddle.net/QpvUQ/7/

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

With preloading, the images are preloaded but many browsers still receive a 304 response for the image causing a flicker on first load. You can force the browser to cache images in the case with rails applications.

[Enable image caching in development mode in Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916813/enable-image-caching-in-development-mode-in-rails-3-1)